# sequence of abscissas x corresponding to equispaced points on any function

Tags: asymptotics, inverse-function, arc-length

I am writing a program where I need to generate the sequence of points $x_1$ , $x_2$, $x_3$,$...$ such that the corresponding ($x_1$, $y_1$), ($x_2$, $y_2$), ($x_3$, $y_3$), $...$  on a generic function $y = f(x)$ are as close as we like but always **equispaced**. The distance is measured as length on the curve $f(x)$ [you might imagine, for instance, taking a semicircle and subdividing it into many small equal arcs, the widths of the slices will be different].

I can assume to restrict to an interval of the $x$ axis and make the subdivisions arbitrarily numerous and small.

Is there some exact asymptotic expression for the generic $x_i$ of the sequence?

(does this problem have a name in math?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that, if we look for a generic solution, it would be necessary to use a local approximation of the function $f(x)$ to obtain an approximation of
$$L=\int_a^b \sqrt{1+[f'(x)]^2}\,dx$$

Using a Taylor expansion of $f(x)$ around $x=a$

$$L= (b-a) \sqrt{f'(a)^2+1}+(b-a)^2\frac{ f'(a) f''(a)}{2
   \sqrt{f'(a)^2+1}}+(b-a)^3\frac{f''(a)^2+f'''(a) f'(a)
   \left(f'(a)^2+1\right)}{6
   \left(f'(a)^2+1\right)^{3/2}}+O\left((b-a)^4\right)$$ Then, using power series reversion,
$$b=a+\frac{L}{\sqrt{f'(a)^2+1}}-\frac{L^2 \left(f'(a) f''(a)\right)}{2
   \left(f'(a)^2+1\right)^2}+$$ $$\frac{L^3 \left(\left(3
   f'(a)^2-1\right) f''(a)^2-f'''(a) f'(a)
   \left(f'(a)^2+1\right)\right)}{6
   \left(f'(a)^2+1\right)^{7/2}}+O\left(L^4\right)$$ we could take as many terms as we wish

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are deriving an approximate expression of the endpoint of a generic arc on the curve. My goal is to find an expression like x = F(f(x)), assuming that y=f(x) are equispaced points on the curve f(x). For instance, in the case of the positive semicircle centered on the origin, I should have something like x = -cos(1-x pi), if I am getting this right.

Comment: @Jada. This is correct. It is a combination of Taylor series followed by power series reversion. If you fix $L$, you compute $(x_1,x_2,\cdots)$. IIf you fix $x_1$, you need to compute $L$. I think that the simplest is the first option.